# Flutter package dependency resolution issue

Tags: android, flutter, dart, package, pubspec

I have following in pubspec.yaml:

```
provider: ^5.0.0
google_maps_place_picker: ^1.0.1
```

But when I run pub get the I receive following error:

```
Because google_maps_place_picker 1.0.1 depends on provider ^4.0.1 and no versions of 
 gogle_maps_place_picker match >1.0.1 <2.0.0, google_maps_place_picker ^1.0.1 requires provider ^4.0.1.
So, because myappxxx depends on both provider ^5.0.0 and google_maps_place_picker ^1.0.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because myappxxx depends on both provider ^5.0.0 and google_maps_place_picker ^1.0.1, version solving failed.)
```

What is the correct way to resolve this dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used google_maps_place_picker but probably you just have to update this dependency to the newest version: https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_place_picker/versions/2.0.0-nullsafety.3.

`google_maps_place_picker: ^1.0.1` --> `google_maps_place_picker: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.3`